# Unused global options in custom class

Tags: documentclass-writing, kvoptions

Consider the following example class file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareBoolOption{foo}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifmyclass@foo
\def\@title{foo}
\else
\def\@title{bar}
\fi

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}
```

And the document

```
\documentclass[foo]{myclass}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It correctly produces a document with title "foo", so the class is actually using the option I gave. However, LaTeX says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [foo].
```

Apparently processing a given option is not enough. How can I mark an option as "used" in order to avoid that warning?

Comment: You can use `\DeclareOption*{}` before `\ProcessOptions\relax`. This will silence LaTeX about any unused or unknown key ....

Comment: Thank you. Would you make this an answer so I can accept it? And as a follow-up question: why is this? How does LaTeX judge whether an option is used or not, what is considered as use of an option? Only passing it to another package or class?

Comment: I could make it answer but it's not really useful, is it? At the moment I can't answer your follow-up question (I would have to excavate the relevant code in `latex.ltx`)

Comment: It's useful in the sense that it solves my problem :) I might add another question about the terminology "used" and "unused" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unused options are added to the `\@unusedoptionlist` macro, which will be printed to the console/log by `\begin{document}` using this code

```
  \ifx\@unusedoptionlist\@empty\else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Unused global option(s):^^J%
            \@spaces[\@unusedoptionlist]}%
  \fi
```

if the list is not `\@empty`.

Using a handler for unused or undefined options named `\DeclareOption*{}` the warnings can be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `\ProcessOptions\relax` in your class file at all? For example, here is a minimal class file (`testkeyval.cls`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testkeyval}[2018/01/19 Test key-value options]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[?]{foo}
\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOptionKey}{article}}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\newcommand\thefoo{`\testkeyval@foo'}
\LoadClass{article}
```

that can be used as follows:

```
\documentclass[foo=bar]{testkeyval}
%\documentclass[foo=bar,11pt]{testkeyval} % passes 11pt to article
%\documentclass[11pt]{testkeyval} % passes 11pt to article
%\documentclass{testkeyval} % default copyright and default fontsize for article
%\documentclass[foo]{testkeyval} % error

\begin{document}
% Number of 'x's on second line: 10pt 0, 11pt 3.
\noindent 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x 

foo is \thefoo.
\end{document}
```

Note that in addition to handling key-value options it passes unused options (such as `11pt`) onto the article class.