# Unused options warning: what does "used" or "unused" mean?

Tags: documentclass-writing

In ([another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326427/unused-global-options-in-custom-class)), it was explained that unused options are added to an internal list and printed out when `\begin{document}` is reached. However, I would like to better understand the terminology. What does it mean to "use" an option?

Certainly, passing it to a loaded package or another class, is considered a use. In my case, I used the options' values to set some custom macros. I would clearly say that I used those options. But apparently this alone is not enough to make the option count as "used".

Comment: I think one main problem is 'removing a option by 'used' some class or package will cause troubles if there's a chain-loading of another class with `\LoadClass` or packages where this option might still have a meaning

Comment: I agree. However, I am defining new options in a custom class, so there is little chance these would make sense in another package, and if they do, then they would surely mean something else. Thus, the user of the class (probably only me...) would not want to pass them along

Comment: I completely understand the point -- my comment above was from a more general point, for a `general` class where it is not clear which options a following class (with `\LoadClass`) will use/accept. The option code system is basically the same for packages and class, while there can be only one `\LoadClass` statement, the number of packages with a variety of options being loaded is 'unlimited'

Comment: Is there any news here? I don't even understand the question/problem.

Comment: `\documentclass[capybara]{article}` `capybara` is used, if any package has defined an option called `capybara`.

Comment: I wanted to know what exactly marks an option as *used* in LaTeX. Of course (as written in the OP), passing an option to a package or the base class will have that effect. However, "using" the option in my class file, e.g. in an if-then-else construction, does not have the effect. So accessing the option (or the variable related to the option) is not enough to mark it *used*.

Comment: I think this is a XY question. You should rather ask why your class is not seeing the options as used instead of asking what makes an option used. Since no code is provided, i vote to close as unclear. Please add a minimal working example that shows the strange behaviour you are seing.

Comment: There is a MWE in the linked question. Have you read it? I don't see what is unclear about my question, especially not in the context. However, as I am not expecting an answer anymore, feel free to close it.